# On the functional equation of the theta function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $\tau$ in the upper half-plane, we define its theta function as

$$ \theta(z) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i (n^2\tau + 2nz)}.$$

This is an entire function. It is well-known that the theta function satisfies the functional equation

$$ \theta(z+\tau)=e^{-\pi i (\tau+2z)}\theta(z).$$

I am trying to show this, but I start from

$$ \theta(z+\tau) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i (n^2\tau + 2nz)} e^{\pi i 2n\tau} $$

and then I have no idea how to proceed. Developing the exponential into a series doesn't look good, it only makes things messier. Any hint?

Comment: Try completing the square.

Comment: @dxdydz On what line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the fact that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}f(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}f(n+1)$$
We then complete the square for $\tau$
$$\begin{align} \theta(z+\tau) &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i (n^2\tau + 2nz)} e^{\pi i 2n\tau} \\&=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i[\tau(n^2+2n+1-1)+2nz]}\\&=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i[\tau(n+1)^2+2(n+1-1)z]}e^{-\pi i\tau}\\&=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i[\tau(n+1)^2+2(n+1)z]}e^{-\pi i(\tau+2z)}\\&=e^{-\pi i(\tau+2z)}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i[\tau(n+1)^2+2(n+1)z]}\\&=e^{-\pi i(\tau+2z)}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{\pi i[\tau n^2+2nz]}\\&=e^{-\pi i(\tau+2z)}\theta(z)\end{align}$$